# How to use the computer modern font in webpages?

Tags: css, fonts

I never see Computer Modern font, the one shipped as default for LaTeX type setting system, on any webpage.

How to change the CSS so that font will *actually* work?

Comment: I haven't heard of a browser that uses LaTeX for typesetting.

Answer (score 65, accepted):

Using the Computer Modern font in webpages has become very easy! Just paste the following lines of CSS code in the head section of your html code in order to activate the sans-serif version of that font.

```
<style type="text/css">
  @font-face {
    font-family: "Computer Modern";
    src: url('http://mirrors.ctan.org/fonts/cm-unicode/fonts/otf/cmunss.otf');
  }
  @font-face {
    font-family: "Computer Modern";
    src: url('http://mirrors.ctan.org/fonts/cm-unicode/fonts/otf/cmunsx.otf');
    font-weight: bold;
  }
  @font-face {
    font-family: "Computer Modern";
    src: url('http://mirrors.ctan.org/fonts/cm-unicode/fonts/otf/cmunsi.otf');
    font-style: italic, oblique;
  }
  @font-face {
    font-family: "Computer Modern";
    src: url('http://mirrors.ctan.org/fonts/cm-unicode/fonts/otf/cmunbxo.otf');
    font-weight: bold;
    font-style: italic, oblique;
  }

  body {
    font-family: "Computer Modern", sans-serif;
  }
</style>
```

Note that the solution here makes the browser load the current version of the fonts from a CTAN mirror, which can be very slow. This is okay for testing purposes, but in the long run I'd recommend you [download](http://cm-unicode.sourceforge.net/download.html) these .otf files to your own webserver.

Comment: Very nice, Holger, I was able to do that.
A good thing also, would be going to [Font Squirrel font-face generator](http://www.fontsquirrel.com/fontface/generator) and squeeze them from 2.2Mb to 291Kb. Now I can have them o website! :)
Also, don't forget to grab the .ttf, not .otf, from the [sf cm-unicode project](http://cm-unicode.sourceforge.net/download.html).

Comment: Although my answer was accepted, this answer is (more) correct.  Paul Irish has an interesting article about this too: http://paulirish.com/2009/bulletproof-font-face-implementation-syntax/

Comment: What about serif variants? It would be nice if someone explained the acronyms of filenames

Comment: @gigabytes by the way if you ever want to really truly understand the filenames check out ctan.org/tex-archive/fonts and drill down to cm/mf the original Knuth Computer Modern metafont files (.mf), each metafont file has an ascii description of what is in it at the top of the file. For example cmb10.mf is Computer Modern Bold Roman 10 point

Comment: gigabytes if you want serif, start with something like this @font-face {
  font-family: 'cmunserif';
  src: url('http://mirrors.ctan.org/fonts/cm-unicode/fonts/otf/cmunrm.otf');
  font-weight: normal;
  font-style: normal;
}
body {
  font-family: 'cmunserif';
}
you can check asmaier 's answer links below for more info

Answer (score 14):

Just for anyone in 2020 and onwards still looking for the optimised web fonts rather than the larger `.otf` fonts which are used in the answers above, I've hosted the Computer Modern font family via the jsDelivr CDN.

To use it, you can add a `<link>` to your html `<head>` which requests the optimised fonts through the following address:

`https://cdn.jsdelivr.net/gh/aaaakshat/cm-web-fonts@latest/fonts.css`

**Example Code:**

```html
<head>
  <!-- Other imports... -->
  <link rel="stylesheet" type="text/css" href="https://cdn.jsdelivr.net/gh/aaaakshat/cm-web-fonts@latest/fonts.css">
  <style>
    body {
      font-family: "Computer Modern Serif", serif;
    }
  </style>
</head>
```

Check out the [documentation here](https://github.com/aaaakshat/cm-web-fonts)

Comment: This is really great!

Answer (score 11):

You can just insert the `https://cdn.rawgit.com/dreampulse/computer-modern-web-font/master/fonts.css` css-stylesheet into your html header. Like this:

```
<head>
  <!-- ... -->

  <link rel="stylesheet" type="text/css" href="https://cdn.rawgit.com/dreampulse/computer-modern-web-font/master/fonts.css">
  <style>
    body {
      font-family: "Computer Modern Sans", sans-serif;
    }
  </style>
</head>
```

You can use the font for production websites with any amount of traffic. Files are served via MaxCDN's super fast global CDN. There is no traffic limits or throttling.

[The README.md on Github](https://github.com/dreampulse/computer-modern-web-font)

Answer (score 9):

Nowadays you can download everything you need (font files and css) from this webpage:

http://checkmyworking.com/cm-web-fonts/

Then the only thing you need to do is to add the corresponding css files to the header section of your html file like:

```
<head>
    <meta charset="UTF-8" />
    <title>Test</title>
    <!-- Computer Modern Serif-->
    <link rel="stylesheet" href="fonts/Serif/cmun-serif.css"></link>
    ...
</head>
```

Answer (score 3):

you cannot, up until CSS 2.1 you can only use the fonts that are ACTUALLY installed on the client's computer. In CSS 3 there are some ways to embed fonts in your webpage but those ways are not greatly supported by browsers yet.
Have a look here: http://home.tiscali.nl/developerscorner/fdc-varia/font-embedding.htm

Answer (score 1):

```
@font-face {
font-family: "Computer Modern ";
src: url(ace.ttf);
}
```

.cm {
    font-family: "Computer Modern";
    }

You do need to have a ttf file for that font.

Comment: "ace.ttf" isn't the Computer Modern font. See my answer to this question.

Answer (score 0):

If you use [KaTeX renderer](https://katex.org) for your website, then you can simply use:

```css
body {
  font-family: "KaTeX_Main";
}
```

There are also other Latin Modern fonts in KaTeX package which you can find [here](https://katex.org/docs/browser.html#loading-as-global).