# Adding Computer Modern Serif to Jekyll github page

Tags: html, css, jekyll, github-pages, webfonts

I am using a forked version of the jekyll github [page](https://github.com/daattali/beautiful-jekyll) and want to add Computer Modern Serif font as the body font for all pages. I downloaded all the files from [here](https://www.checkmyworking.com/cm-web-fonts/#serif) as explained by the [answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/26817599/16168476) into a `fonts/Serif` folder. I then added into the `_includes/ext-css.html` file the following code

```
<head>
    <meta charset="UTF-8" />
    <title>Test</title>
    <!-- Computer Modern Serif-->
    <link rel="stylesheet" href="fonts/Serif/cmun-serif.css"></link>
    ...
</head>
```

I have also added the following line (at line 13) to the `assets/css/beautifuljekyll.css` file

```
body {
  font-family: 'Lora', 'Times New Roman', serif;
```

However, I am still unable to get this font on all the pages. Should I add/remove anything else to make this work? I am new to github pages and html, so please help me with this

Answer (score 1, accepted):

After a few discussions (thanks to [araxhiel](https://www.reddit.com/user/araxhiel/)) I found a way to fix the issue.

1. In the `_includes/ext-css.html` file add `/fonts/` instead of just fonts i.e. make the code as

```
<head>
    <meta charset="UTF-8" />
    <title>Test</title>
    <!-- Computer Modern Serif-->
    <link rel="stylesheet" href="/fonts/Serif/cmun-serif.css"></link>
    ...
</head>
```

2. At line 13 of `assets/css/beautifuljekyll.css` file change it to

```
body {
  font-family: 'Computer Modern Serif','Droid Sans', Helvetica, Arial, sans-serif;
```

And also, in the same file, add the following piece of code just before this line 13 (before body starts)

```
//*********************** Fonts ********************//

@font-face {
    font-family: 'Computer Modern Serif';
    src: url('../../fonts/Serif/cmunrm.eot');
    src: url('../../fonts/Serif/cmunrm.eot?#iefix') format('embedded-opentype'),
         url('../../fonts/Serif/cmunrm.woff') format('woff'),
         url('../../fonts/Serif/cmunrm.ttf') format('truetype'),
         url('../../fonts/Serif/cmunrm.svg#cmunrm') format('svg');
    font-weight: normal;
    font-style: normal;
}


@font-face {
    font-family: 'Computer Modern Serif';
    src: url('../../fonts/Serif/cmunbx.eot');
    src: url('../../fonts/Serif/cmunbx.eot?#iefix') format('embedded-opentype'),
         url('../../fonts/Serif/cmunbx.woff') format('woff'),
         url('../../fonts/Serif/cmunbx.ttf') format('truetype'),
         url('../../fonts/Serif/cmunbx.svg#cmunbx') format('svg');
    font-weight: bold;
    font-style: normal;
}

@font-face {
    font-family: 'Computer Modern Serif';
    src: url('../../fonts/Serif/cmunti.eot');
    src: url('../../fonts/Serif/cmunti.eot?#iefix') format('embedded-opentype'),
         url('../../fonts/Serif/cmunti.woff') format('woff'),
         url('../../fonts/Serif/cmunti.ttf') format('truetype'),
         url('../../fonts/Serif/cmunti.svg#cmunti') format('svg');
    font-weight: normal;
    font-style: italic;
}


@font-face {
    font-family: 'Computer Modern Serif';
    src: url('../../fonts/Serif/cmunbi.eot');
    src: url('../../fonts/Serif/cmunbi.eot?#iefix') format('embedded-opentype'),
         url('../../fonts/Serif/cmunbi.woff') format('woff'),
         url('../../fonts/Serif/cmunbi.ttf') format('truetype'),
         url('../../fonts/Serif/cmunbi.svg#cmunbi') format('svg');
    font-weight: bold;
    font-style: italic;
}
```

3. Along with the above two code additions, if you follow the steps in the question, which only leaves adding the `fonts/Serif` folder onto the main repo from the [link](https://www.checkmyworking.com/cm-web-fonts/#serif), you are good to go!!